# TypeError: Invalid PostCSS Plugin found at: plugins[0]

Tags: next.js, postcss, tailwind-css

I cloned this repo https://github.com/tailwindcss/setup-examples/tree/master/examples/nextjs then I updated `tailwind.config.js`

```
  theme: {
    extend: {
      color: {
        primary: "#730000",
        secondry: "#efefef",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

then run the command `postcss css/tailwind.css -o generated.css`
terminal throws an error `TypeError: Invalid PostCSS Plugin found at: plugins[0]`
can anyone please help me to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: No, then I switched to another solution if you want I can create a quick repo for u. Still, there is a problem compiler does not watch the changes.

Comment: hey, i guess i found the solution, could you please update the question and also provide your `postcss.config.js` file content?

Comment: could u please share you solution?

Comment: of course, ill write it as answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

changed this

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "postcss-import",
    "tailwindcss",
    "autoprefixer",
  ]
};
```

to

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("postcss-import"),
    require("tailwindcss"),
    require("autoprefixer"),
  ]
};
```

solved the

> TypeError: Invalid PostCSS Plugin found at: plugins[0]

Comment: this works for me, but then production build has all the CSS approximately 60000 lines

Comment: yes, to solve it you must use `purge css`, it documented well here [Tailwind-Nextjs-PurgeCSS](https://github.com/tailwindcss/setup-examples/tree/master/examples/nextjs#setting-up-purgecss-optional)

Answer (score 7):

### Same error, possibly different issue as OP

I had this issue when attempting to install Storybook alongside Tailwind and Nextjs. I was able to fix the error after adding `"tailwindcss": {},` to my `postcss.config.js`.

To be clear, I have not and did not experience this issue as you did, without attempting to add storybook to the workflow.

### My solution's working configuration files

Below are working configurations for postcss, tailwind, storybook, using defaults for Nextjs. I am using the standard `create-next-app` workflow and based on the `--example with-storybook`.

In particular, all of the files below are placed in my project root directory and I used storybook >= 6.0.0.

> ⚠️ See [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config), *near the bottom in a note section*, which highlights the need for object syntax in configuration files when adding non-Next.js tools, such as storybook.

`postcss.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    "tailwindcss": {},
    'postcss-flexbugs-fixes': {},
    'postcss-preset-env': {
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009',
      },
      stage: 3,
      features: {
        'custom-properties': false,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

`tailwind.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  future: {
    removeDeprecatedGapUtilities: true,
    purgeLayersByDefault: true
  },
  purge: ['./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'accent-1': '#333',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

`.storybook/main.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../stories/*.stories.@(ts|tsx|js|jsx|mdx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-actions', '@storybook/addon-links'],
}
```

`.storybook/preview.js`

```js
import '../styles/index.css';
```

where `index.css` is as instructed via the [Tailwindcss docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#add-tailwind-to-your-css).

Answer (score 4):

Check the version of autoprefixer you have installed. It took me an hour or two to realize that autoprefixer version 10 is indeed causing breaking changes when used with nextjs+tailwindcss (specifically next's css-loader on my end). Rollback to autoprefixer@9.8.6 for the time being until these bugs are resolved. Also ensure you aren't using next@9.5.3 if using yarn. Use next@9.5.2 or next@9.5.4-canary.20. The reason I mention it is because next@9.5.3 automatically installs if no explicit version is targeted which clashes with yarn. Thankfully, next@9.5.4-canary.20 should be released as @9.5.4 soon and they'll begin work on @9.5.5-canary.x

Autoprefixer published version 10 approximately 5 days ago. They moved postcss to peerDependencies and moved to PostCSS 8. They also removed support for Node versions 6.x, 8.x, and 11.x. That said, autoprefixer@9.8.6 should do the trick.

I left a comment on an open issue in postcss/autoprefixer outlining the error I was getting on my end with regards to using version 10 with nextjs https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/1359#issuecomment-695752807

Answer (score 1):

Try updating postcss-cli along with postcss, tailwindcss and autoprefixer to their **latest** versions.

```sh
npm i postcss-cli@latest

npm i tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

Worked for me in ReactJS - "^16.13.1"

#### postcss.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("tailwindcss"),
    require("autoprefixer"),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated postcss-cli (10.0.0v) and autoprefixer(10.4.8v) to the latest, then added `require("postcss-import")` in `postcss.config.js` file solved the issue for me.

1. `npm i postcss-cli@latest autoprefixer@latest`
2. `postcss.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("postcss-import"),
    require("tailwindcss"),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('cssnano')({
      preset: 'default',
    }),
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me,
thank you,

Updated postcss-cli (10.0.0v) and autoprefixer(10.4.8v) to the latest, then added require("postcss-import") in postcss.config.js file solved the issue for me.

1.NPM i postcss-cli@latest autoprefixer@latest
2.postcss.config.js: